# purple screen on load ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04, freeze, additional-drivers

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 and windows 11. I changed nvidia driver then reboot ubuntu. I selected ubuntu in grub but i cannot access login. I am sctuck in a purple/black creen without any cursor neither a way to display a terminal.
I am able to log in unbuntu via recovery mode. Windows boots normaly.

I tried many solution found on the internet without success :

- boot on nomodeset
- uninstall & reinstall nvidia drivers
- remove X.org confid
- apt update & upgrade

I don't what to do now

Here is my config :
ASUS TUF DASH 15 - nvidia RTX3060 - 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-11370H @ 3.30GHz × 8 - Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS - llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7, 256 bits)